# Google map is not loading with the new API key

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using 'react-native-maps' to show a map inside a page. For that I've configured an API key in android manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="my key here"/>
```

Its working fine.

Now I Got my new API key from the client.When I configured with the new key, Map is not loading at all. Everything else(places auto fill, reverse Geo coding) etc are working fine. 
IS there any service I need to enable on the client's **Google Cloud Platform Console.**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely means that your client's API key:

(a) is restricted with HTTP referrers or by IP address. To load a Google map from an Android app, you need to secure this key with [Android restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict_key). So your client will have to create a second API key and restrict each [accordingly](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#api_key_table).

(b) belongs to a project that has the Maps SDK for Android disabled. [Enabling it](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#enable-api-sdk) will fix it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @evan. I will check with the Client then.. Accepting the answer(Already upvoted though)

Comment: Thank you! Happy to help :)